# Searching for specific words that appear on a website from more than one text file or one file via split

Tags: c#

Search for a word inside a website Via text file
The program takes word for word when the error message defined inside appears
(errorMessage2)
Then it goes directly to split

```
temp = data[i].Split('|');
```

And it starts right after split

txt file : s1 s2 s3 s4
| <<< split
s1 s2 s3 s4
Or by opening another text file

```
 for (int m = 0; m < listBox3.Items.Count; m++)
                {

                    if (listBox3.Items[m].ToString() == errorMessage2)
                    {
                        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save this error ?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
                        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            writerWCC.WriteLine(data[i]);
                            
                        }

                            
                    }

                }
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , we are happy to help you if there is any new question,

Comment: Could you please share your code, so we'll better understand the issue?

Comment: I put the code @UriY